# Intellisense not working for ViewModel for MVC2 project in ASP.NET MVC2 RTW

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

I upgraded to MVC2 RTM with VS2010 RC and some of my ViewUserControl and Page controls don't show intellisense for simple things like <%= Html..... %> or <%= Model... %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an Area that is having problems then there is probably a missing Web.Config file in the Areas project. Without it Visual Studio thinks you're using a 'traditional' aspx or asmx file.

- Right click on the MVC project and select 'Add'
- Choose 'Area' from the dropdown
- Copy the `Web.Config` file that was generated into your original Area

It should work now.